# How to make windows authentication work in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication

I am building an ASP.NET MVC intranet app for my organization and want to get the network user name. I have the following in my Web.config

```
<system.web>
     <authentication mode="Windows"> </authentication>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
```

When I am debugging with IIS Express, `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` gives my windows username.

However, when in deploy my app on IIS, `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` is coming as `"NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"` instead of the windows username.

In IIS, for my app, I have enabled just Windows Authentication and disabled other types of authentication.

What change do I need to make in IIS so that `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` gives the logged in windows username?

Comment: What happens if you remove the allow element?

Answer (score -3):

Find any guide from Microsoft at Google, and they will tell you that you forgot to enable Windows authentication on IIS and disable anonymous authentication.

Comment: This answer is not relevant given information stated in the question.

Comment: @Khyron Do you know IIS at all? Seeing IUSR means anonymous authentication is on, and how can this be not the answer?

Comment: Ironically, that's a better answer.

Comment: @Lex Li No, as I said in the question, Windows Authentication is enabled and all other authentication disabled.

Comment: Thanks, I missed to turn off anonynous authentication for the "Web Site". I only turned it off for the Application.